# Function app can't read key vault secrets - bad request

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have setup a function app with system managed identiy and a key vault that has set access policies to Get, List, Set, Delete, Recover for this function app set as principal:

[image]

[image]

I have tried these snippets but all gave me the same error:

Test 1:

```
var secretUriString = "https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net";
            Uri keyvaultUri = new System.Uri(secretUriString);

            var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
            SecretClient keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(keyvaultUri, credential);
            
            var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(SecretURI(secretnamestring))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Test 2:

```
var secretUriString = "https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net";
        Uri secretUri = new System.Uri(secretUriString);

        SecretClient keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(secretUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
        
        var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(SecretURI(secretnamestring))
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I run a function in this function app on azure or locally and I get this error:

```
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.824Z] Executed 'functionInTheFunctionApp' (Failed, Id=39df84b7-3b9a-410d-8d93-af5424fa745e, Duration=506ms)
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.824Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: UserAccessProcessios3. Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets: Service request failed.
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.825Z] Status: 400 (Bad Request)
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.826Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.826Z] Content:
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.827Z] <!DOCTYPE html>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.827Z] <html>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.828Z]     <head>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.829Z]         <title>Runtime Error</title>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.829Z]         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.830Z]         <style>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.831Z]          body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.832Z]          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.832Z]          b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.833Z]          H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.834Z]          H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.835Z]          pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.835Z]          .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.836Z]          .version {color: gray;}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.836Z]          .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.837Z]          .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.838Z]          @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.838Z]           pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.839Z]          }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.840Z]          @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.840Z]           pre { width: 280px; }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.841Z]          }
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.842Z]         </style>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.842Z]     </head>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.843Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.843Z]     <body bgcolor="white">
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.844Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.844Z]             <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.845Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.845Z]             <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.846Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.847Z]             <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.848Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.848Z]             <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.849Z]             <br><br>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.850Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.850Z]             <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.851Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.851Z]             <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.852Z]                <tr>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.853Z]                   <td>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.853Z]                       <code><pre>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.854Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.854Z] &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.855Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.855Z] &lt;configuration&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.856Z]     &lt;system.web&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.857Z]         &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.857Z]     &lt;/system.web&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.858Z] &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.858Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.859Z]                   </td>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.859Z]                </tr>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.860Z]             </table>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.861Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.861Z]             <br>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.862Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.862Z]             <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.863Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.864Z]             <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.864Z]                <tr>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.865Z]                   <td>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.866Z]                       <code><pre>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.866Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.867Z] &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.868Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.868Z] &lt;configuration&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.869Z]     &lt;system.web&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.869Z]         &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.870Z]     &lt;/system.web&gt;
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.870Z] &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.871Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.871Z]                   </td>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.872Z]                </tr>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.873Z]             </table>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.873Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.874Z]             <br>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.874Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.875Z]     </body>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.875Z] </html>
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.876Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.876Z]
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.877Z] Headers:
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.878Z] Cache-Control: private
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.878Z] X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.879Z] Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.880Z] Date: Sat, 03 Dec 2022 10:16:16 GMT
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.880Z] Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.881Z] Content-Length: 3420
[2022-12-03T10:16:16.882Z] .
```

AppInsight inner log doesn't guide me what the problem is:

```
        Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108)
Inner exception Azure.RequestFailedException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient.GetSecret (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at functionapprojectname.HelperMethods+<GetKVPassword>d__24.MoveNext (functionapprojectname, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\directory\Function1.cs:3386)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at functionappprojectname.Function1+<UserAccessProcessios3>d__9.MoveNext (functionappprojectname, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\directory\Function1.cs:4313)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__33.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:581)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:527)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:306)
```

Packages installed in latest VS2022:
[image]
[image]

Comment: you should check the inner exception to see what s going wrong first

Comment: Hi @Thomas I checked in AppInsights but the stack trace inner exception doesn't guide me where to find the problem, I've added this to the post above at the end, thank you

Answer (score 1):

- Here in the `getSecretAsync` try passing the name of the secret as a string.
- Here just like you I created an azure function and added the permission for it in the azure key vault. Here I have a http trigger which will return the secret from the key vault. Also the  secret value here is `hello world`

Mycode:

```
var cred = new ManagedIdentityCredential();// new DefaultAzureCredential();

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("<Key Vault URL >"),cred);

var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("Name of Secret ").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @MohitGranorkar, this worked for me. Also I was assigning the value of secret value incorrectly , now I see that to get the value is ClientSecret sec = new ClientSecret(); then sec.keyIDValue = secret.Value.Value;

Comment: From yesterday to today there may have been some windows update. The function app no longer compiled with error. After much tinkering I removed Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets and the functions compile and run again. However trying this code you kindly posted with either new ManagedIdentityCredential() or new DefaultAzureCredential() does not authorize me to the vault. However the error is no longer bad request bun unauthorized, I'll therefore raise a separate post for this.